# Add custom compiler warning to virtual method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-warnings, roslyn

I'm extending one of our companies libraries so that my co-workers can inherit from a class of our business logic. This will require them to be able to overwrite certain methods. However I'm running into a similar problem like when overriding the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` logic.

Visual Studio issues a compiler warning when you just override one of these methods. It would be really nice to use that so that if my colleague should forget to override the method he would get a warning if not also overriding the other method?

Is it somehow possible (maybe with an Attribute etc.) to add a custom compiler warning to your class method in Visual Studio that overriding just one method might cause inconsistent behaviour?

Comment: That's a job for an analyzer, eg a Roslyn Analyzer

Comment: @rakwaht you linked to a Java question. None of the answers is relevant in .NET. For example, Roslyn in .NET allows you easily create an analyzer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry I somehow thought it was Java comment deleted

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thx for the idea with the analyzer - it looks like a rather complex approach however. I guess there is no lightweight option to do this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing as specific as that. I think your options are:

1. Write a custom analyzer, as suggested by Panagiotis Kanavos. That analyzer could either be specific to your type, or it could detect the presence of an attribute, as you suggested.

   I think that the resulting analyzer would not be very complex, but learning how to write it could take some time, if you've never used the Roslyn API.
2. Figure out a different coding pattern that achieves a similar purpose. For example, you could have one type where both methods are `abstract` (so you have to override both) and one where they are `sealed` (so you can't override them).

   I'm not sure if this specific approach would be worth it, but maybe something similar is worth considering.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted to read but I will have to live with it I guess. Just trying to estimate which is going to be less time consuming... re-implementing half the library or learning Roslyn.

Comment: Well, here's an [intro to the latter](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix).